# Group and rank consecutive values by condition in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table `mytable` to which I would like to add two additional columns

My objective is to group by `user_id` and `mobile_id` **only** where there is a continuous sequence of values where `difftime > - 600` . The sequence must be consecutive in `created_at` (timestamp), and given a rank, starting again if it is the same user and mobile id but a `difftime` occurs < - 600.  Each separate group would be assigned an incremental value.  For example:

```
> mytable
            created_at user_id mobile_id   status difftime
1  2019-01-02 22:01:38 1227604     68409 finished      \\N
2  2019-01-03 04:08:29 1227604     68409 finished     -366
3  2019-01-03 15:16:38 1227604     68409  timeout     -668
4  2019-01-04 00:34:40 1227604     68409   failed     -558
5  2019-01-04 00:27:37 1227605     68453   failed      \\N
6  2019-01-04 00:35:56 1227605     68453 finished       -8
7  2019-01-04 01:39:52 1227605     68453 finished      -63
8  2019-01-04 02:05:53 1227605     68453  timeout      -26
9  2019-01-04 02:17:17 1227605     68453  timeout      -11
10 2019-01-04 16:51:39 1227605     68453  timeout     -874
```

Would create an output of

```
> output
            created_at user_id mobile_id   status difftime group rank
1  2019-01-02 22:01:38 1227604     68409 finished      \\N    NA   NA
2  2019-01-03 04:08:29 1227604     68409 finished     -366     1    1
3  2019-01-03 15:16:38 1227604     68409  timeout     -668    NA   NA
4  2019-01-04 00:34:40 1227604     68409   failed     -558     2    1
5  2019-01-04 00:27:37 1227605     68453   failed      \\N    NA   NA
6  2019-01-04 00:35:56 1227605     68453 finished       -8     3    1
7  2019-01-04 01:39:52 1227605     68453 finished      -63     3    2
8  2019-01-04 02:05:53 1227605     68453  timeout      -26     3    3
9  2019-01-04 02:17:17 1227605     68453  timeout      -11     3    4
10 2019-01-04 16:51:39 1227605     68453  timeout     -874    NA   NA
```

When I simply try to assign a rank, the following query throws an error: `WHERE clause cannot contain aggregations, window functions or grouping operations`

Although I am using Presto SQL, any SQL solution here would be helpful to help think about how to restructure the query

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, mobile_id ORDER BY created_at) as rank
    from mytable
    WHERE DATE_DIFF('minute', created_at, lag(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, mobile_id ORDER BY user_id, created_at)) > -600
    ORDER BY user_id, mobile_id, created_at
```

Comment: Yes even in MS SQL windows functions are not allowed in where clause, I think you can use the same condition in your select list and use it as subquery, and filter out where the difference is less than -600

Comment: Unfortunately that does not take into account instances where there are values less than -600 in the group or rank.   Please provide an example to illustrate this

Comment: Does Presto SQL support CTEs? In SQL Server, windowing functions can't be used in a WHERE clause, as @Avi mentions, but they can be used in CTEs. The columns generated from the windowed function can then be used in WHERE clauses. If it doesn't support CTEs, try putting them in a sub-select in the FROM clause and doing your WHERE that way, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the groups, do a cumulative sum of the values that are "invalid".  Then use `dense_rank()` to assign a value.

I have no idea what your query has to do with your problem, but the logic would be like this:

```
select t.*, grp,
       (case when difftime > -600
             then row_number() over (partition by user_id, mobile_id order by created_at)
        end) as rank
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by user_id, mobile_id order by grouping) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when difftime > -600 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id, mobile_id order by created_at) as grouping
            from t
            ) t
     ) t
```